# How can I import data into google sheets when the URL is formatted as data:text/csv;base64

Tags: csv, google-sheets, import, data-uri

I am trying to import data into a google sheet by using the =IMPORTDATA("URL") function from this website https://public.domo.com/embed/pages/dPRol However the CSV file link is formatted as a data URL as such

data:text/csv;base64,RXZlbnRSZXNpZGVudENvdW50eSxJbmRpdmlkdWFscyBUZXN0ZWQsSW5kaXZpZHVhbHMgUG9zaXRpdmUsVG90YWwgUmVjb3ZlcmVkLFRvdGFsIERlYXRocw0KUG9sayw4MTA4Niw5NDc5LDY1NjQsMjAxDQpMaW5uLDMxMjg5LDIwMDUsMTU3Miw4Nw0KSm9obnNvbiwyMzMyOSwxODgxLDEzNjMsMTUNCkJsYWNrIEhhd2ssMjMyODQsMjk3MCwyMjQ2LDYyDQpTY290dCwyMjk

The import function in sheets does not seem to recognize the URL in this format. Would there be another way to import in this data.

The object of this is to create a source that auto updates when the data is updated. Perhaps there would be another solution other than google sheets.

Comment: I know this isn't what you want because it constantly needs refreshing, but a free tool like https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html might be a starting point (and works perfectly with your sample)

Comment: Hi there @JakeTornholm! As @TomSharpe said, you could use a website to translate that code. Another workaround is to use Apps Script to programmatically convert base64 data, would that be a valid approach in your situation?